# Customizing the cart of "OpenCart"

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to make a few changes to the actual cart in OpenCart.
As for now when adding a product to the cart information will be shown the following way:

```
Product1     Amount:
Size: XL       2
```

And a new row is created if the same product, but with a different size, is added to the cart.
My wish is to get the following design of the cart

```
Product1     S  M  L  XL
             1        2
```

So, that each product will only create one, single line and then show the correct amount under the corresponding size categories.
This is my code so far:

```
<?php
            $saveName = array();
            $sizesArray = array("S","M","L","XL");
            $x = 0;
                if($products || $vouchers) {
                    foreach ($products as $product){
                        foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
                            $option['value'];
                            }

                    $saveName[$x] = $product['name'].'|'.$option['value'].'|'.$product['quantity'];
                    $seperateValues = explode("|",$saveName[$x]);
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="image"><?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a>
                        <?php } ?></td>
                      <td class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></td>

                        <?php
                        foreach($sizesArray as $sizes){
                            if($sizes == $seperateValues[1]){
                                echo '<td>'.$seperateValues[0].' '.$seperateValues[2].'</td>';
                                }
                            else{
                                echo '<td>0</td>';
                                }
                        }
                        ?>

                      <td class="total"><?php echo $product['total']; ?></td>
                      <td class="remove">Remove</td>
                    </tr>


                    <?php
                    $x++;
                    } 
                    ?>
```

The code formats the amount under the right category, but I can't get it to produce only one row for each product. Any help is much appriciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the template is not going to do the job, because Opencart internally stores products in array in a format product_id:serialized_array_of_options, so products with the same id but different option combinations are stored separately. You can see that in /system/library/cart.php, in the getProducts method:

```
foreach ($this->session->data['cart'] as $key => $quantity) {

    $product = explode(':', $key);
    $product_id = $product[0];
    $stock = true;

    // Options
    if (isset($product[1])) {
        $options = unserialize(base64_decode($product[1]));
    } else {
        $options = array();
    }
```

So to achieve, what you want, you will have make changes to the way Cart class stores products in the session.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to edit the code to get the result that I need?